# How to move entire folders without CLI?

Tags: github

I've been making a script that tests XSS vulnerabilities [(Slingshot.XSS)](https://github.com/keeganjk/slingshot.xss). At first, I was only doing JavaScript tests, but now I want to add some for PHP or Perl. So I have the `slingshot.xss/payloads/`, and many folders for JS payloads in there. I recently made a `slingshot.xss/payloads/javascript` directory. Now I want to add all of my folders and files in `slingshot.xss/payloads/` moved to `slingshot.xss/payloads/javascript`. How would I do this (without the CLI)?

Comment: Are you finding for online solutions? For local copies, do this in a file manager and git will automatically handle everything for you.

Comment: OK, thanks! Submit that as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the folder, Git is able to detect such operations.

In detail, if the files are same, it's treated as rename, and if most percentage of the files are identical, it's treated as rename+rewrite.